# Enviar datos de checkbox a php para actualizar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

soy nuevo en esto... cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Tengo una vista modal donde cargo una tabla,tengo un checkbox por cada fila, quiero actualizar los campos que únicamente estén seleccionados, (obtener los valores de los elementos que estén seleccionados) para luego hacer un update, actualmente este es mi código, muchas gracias a las personas que me puedan ayudar

```
<td><?php echo $verDetalle['itemCode'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $verDetalle['dscription'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $verDetalle['causal'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $verDetalle['mensaje'] ?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $verDetalle['id_linea'] ?>" id ="ErrorPrecio"/>
    </td>
```

con el id del checkbox estoy obteniendo el valor con la propiedad .val() pero solo metoca un unico valor... el primero

esto es lo que hago con javaascript

```
$("#prueba").click(function(){

errorPrecio=$('#ErrorPrecio').val();

  cadena= "errorPrecio="+ errorPrecio;

alert(cadena);

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/actualizaPrecio.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(r){
          if (r==false) {

          alertify.error("Fallo la transaccion, Intente de nuevo o contacte al Administrador");

          }else{

          alertify.success("Actualizado con exito");


          }
        }


      });


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

no entiendo bien lo que necesitas hacer, pero si lo que quieres es ejecutar una actualización mediante AJAX en base a los checkboxs, es necesario que realices una comprobación de cada checkbox, lo puedes hacer el el JQuery:

```
if($('#ErrorPrecio').prop('checked')){
    //realizas tu petición AJAX...
}
```

Ahora, si lo necesitas para varios checkbox, los datos los almacenas en una única variable y los mandas en un AJAX, obviamente deberás tener un script php que esté preparado para recibir múltiples datos y realizar las actualizaciones correspondientes.
[Aquí](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) puedes obtener más información a cerca del método **prop()**.

**Actualización**

Para varios checkbox deberás hacer para cada uno su respectiva comprobación y añadirla a tu variable que enviarás por AJAX:

```
var data = "?";
if($('#checkbox1').prop('checked')){
    data += "checkbox1="+('#checkbox1').val()+"&";
}
if($('#checkbox2').prop('checked')){
    data += "checkbox2="+('#checkbox1').val()+"&";
}
//....
```

Lo siguiente sería ejecutar tu AJAX y en tu script php deberías buscar cada variable que has mandado:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])){
    //...haces lo que necesitas para el checkbox1
}
//haces lo mismo para los demás
?>
```

Comment: Hola luis gracias por tu respuesta, si efectivamente lo que encesito es capturar el valor de varios checkbox y realziar un update el problema que tengo es que solo obtengo el valor de un checkbox y no de varios

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo, solo debes concatenar los valores que necesitas mandar con '&' empezando con un ?, y en tu php podrás rescatar estos valores de acuerdo al nombre que les asignes en la concatenación. Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.